# Block the access of random url paths with Apache mod_rewrite

Tags: mod-rewrite, redirect

This is the link to my website manuals:

```
https://www.example.com/manual/ch016_user-moves.xhtml
```

but unfortunately it can be accessed also this way :

```
https://www.example.com/manual/blablablafoobar/ch016_user-moves.xhtml
```

or

```
https://www.example.com/manual/what-ever-youwanttoputinhere/ch016_user-moves.xhtml
```

the second way also causes missing images and files as the URL its not a known path. How can I block or redirect those random paths added in the URL between the `/manual/` and `file.xhtml`?

The only rules in my vhost configurations are this :

```
RewriteEngine on
        RewriteRule ^/manual/(.*).xhtml /manual/index.php/$1 [PT]
        RewriteRule ^/manual/(.*).html /manual/index.php/$1 [PT]
        Alias /manual /home/piatek/chess-manual/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that these URLs are accessible in the first place would seem to be because of your existing directives:

> ```
> RewriteRule ^/manual/(.*).xhtml /manual/index.php/$1 [PT]
> RewriteRule ^/manual/(.*).html /manual/index.php/$1 [PT]
> ```

Specifically, `(.*)` matches *anything* - in other words, an unlimited URL-path depth (which is then left for your `index.php` script to decipher - which it presumably does successfully!). Try restricting this to `([^/]+)` so that it will only match a filename and not the entire URL-path. These two directives can also be combined into one.

For example, try the following instead of the above two directives:

```
RewriteRule ^/manual/([^/]+)\.x?html$ /manual/index.php/$1 [PT]
```

This will probably result in these "invalid" URLs returning a 404.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response, it solved my issue.